# How to select combobox by id or value using with BeanItemContainer?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am using [BeanItemContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItemContainer.html) for my comboboxes to satisfy key-value pairs.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ComboBoxItem implements Serializable {
private String id;
private String description;

public ComboBoxItem(final String id, final String description) {
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
}

public final void setId(final String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public final void setDescription(final String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public final String getId() {
    return id;
}

public final String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
```

}

I created a sample combobox as below

```
    List<ComboBoxItem> lstAuctionDateList = new ArrayList<ComboBoxItem>();
    lstAuctionDateList.add(new ComboBoxItem("all", "All"));
    BeanItemContainer<ComboBoxItem> auctionDateItems = new BeanItemContainer<ComboBoxItem>(ComboBoxItem.class,
            lstAuctionDateList);
    final ComboBox cbAuctionDate = new ComboBox("Auction Date", auctionDateItems);
    cbAuctionDate.addStyleName("small");
    cbAuctionDate.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    cbAuctionDate.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    cbAuctionDate.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");
    cbAuctionDate.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        public void valueChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
            if (cbAuctionDate.getValue() != null) {
                System.out.println(((ComboBoxItem) cbAuctionDate.getValue()).getId());
                System.out.println(((ComboBoxItem) cbAuctionDate.getValue()).getDescription());
            }

        }
    });
```

It is fine but I can't select any of combobox items by using below codes

```
    cbAuctionDate.select("all");
    cbAuctionDate.select("All");
    cbAuctionDate.setValue("all");
    cbAuctionDate.setValue("All");
```

What am I wrong ? How can I select my comboxes by programmatically ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when using a (bean) container and adding items, the identity of the item itself is used as the itemId in the container.  E.g. `cbActionDate.select(lstAuctionDateList[0])` should work.

You either have yo make your objects immutable or use ways to tell the container, what it has to use for an id (E.g. [`setBeanIdProperty("id")`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanContainer.html#setBeanIdProperty%28java.lang.Object%29) or `setBeanIdResolver`).

Making the object immutable should be easy right now (make the class and the private attributes final, drop the setters and let your IDE generate `equals` and `hashCode` for you)

Comment: `cbAuctionDate.select(lstAuctionDateList.get(0));` ... it is really work. Thanks sir !

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need the cbAuctionDate.addItem("All") call, you already have such a item in your collection
2. I would try it that way:

> ```
> List<ComboBoxItem> lstAuctionDateList = new ArrayList<ComboBoxItem>();
> ComboBoxItem allItems= new ComboBoxItem("all", "All");
> lstAuctionDateList.add(allItems);
> ....
> ...
> cbAuctionDate.select(allItems);
> ```

Comment: yes ! I will fix your suggestion no 1 right now . I agree it is needless.

Comment: Now my combobox is empty . Am I need to set **ItemCaptionPropertyId** ? Now I am still using `cbAuctionDate.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");`. I didn't get yet.

Comment: When you don't specify anything, then the toString() method is used for the display property

Answer (score 1):

Now I created custom ComboBox component for my problem

```
public class ComboBox extends CustomComponent implements Serializable {
private com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox comboBox;
private BeanItemContainer<ComboBoxItem> entries = new BeanItemContainer<ComboBoxItem>(ComboBoxItem.class);

public ComboBox() {
    comboBox = new com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox();
    comboBox.addStyleName("small");
    comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    setCompositionRoot(comboBox);
}
public ComboBox(final String caption) {
    comboBox = new com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox();
    comboBox.addStyleName("small");
    comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    setCaption(caption);
    setCompositionRoot(comboBox);
}

public ComboBox(final String caption, final List<ComboBoxItem> items) {
    comboBox = new com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox();
    comboBox.addStyleName("small");
    comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
    setCaption(caption);
    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
        entries.addAll(items);
        comboBox.setContainerDataSource(entries);
        comboBox.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
        addItems(entries);
        comboBox.select(items.get(0));
        comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");
    }

    setCompositionRoot(comboBox);
}
public final void addItems(final List<ComboBoxItem> items) {
    if (items != null && items.size() > 0) {
        entries.addAll(items);
        comboBox.setContainerDataSource(entries);
        comboBox.setItemCaptionMode(ItemCaptionMode.PROPERTY);
        addItems(entries);
        comboBox.select(items.get(0));
        comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");
    }
}
private void addItems(final BeanItemContainer<ComboBoxItem> items) {
    comboBox.addItems(items);
}

public final void addItem(final ComboBoxItem item) {
    if (item != null) {
        comboBox.setContainerDataSource(entries);
        comboBox.addItem(item);
        comboBox.setItemCaptionPropertyId("description");
    }
}

public final void selectByIndex(final int index) {
    Object[] ids = comboBox.getItemIds().toArray();
    comboBox.select(((ComboBoxItem) ids[index]));
}

public final void selectById(final String id) {
    Object[] ids = comboBox.getItemIds().toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (((ComboBoxItem) ids[i]).getId().equals(id)) {
            selectByIndex(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public final void selectByItemText(final String description) {
    Object[] ids = comboBox.getItemIds().toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (((ComboBoxItem) ids[i]).getDescription().equals(description)) {
            selectByIndex(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public final int getItemCount() {
    return comboBox.getItemIds().toArray().length;
}

public final String getSelectedId() {
    return ((ComboBoxItem) comboBox.getValue()).getId();
}
public final String getSelectedItemText() {
    return ((ComboBoxItem) comboBox.getValue()).getDescription();
}

public final void addValueChangeListener(final ValueChangeListener listener) {
    comboBox.addValueChangeListener(listener);
}
}
```

and below is test codes

```
    final ComboBox combo = new ComboBox("My ComboBox");
    combo.addItem(new ComboBoxItem("all", "All"));
    // Add with list
    List<ComboBoxItem> items = new ArrayList<ComboBoxItem>();
    items.add(new ComboBoxItem("one", "One"));
    items.add(new ComboBoxItem("two", "Two"));
    items.add(new ComboBoxItem("three", "Three"));
    combo.addItems(items);

    combo.addItem(new ComboBoxItem("four", "Four"));
    combo.addItem(new ComboBoxItem("five", "five"));
    combo.selectByIndex(3);
    combo.addValueChangeListener(new ValueChangeListener() {

        public void valueChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedId() + " --- " + combo.getSelectedItemText());

        }
    });
```